# h.264 video voice is fine but has no video image on iphone6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, video, encoding

I have a `.ts` file containing H.264 video. The AAC audio (voice) part is fine but file has no video image on iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 7, same file (its video and sound) all work correct on Android phone (operating system is Android 6.0).

I ran the video through Potplayer:

```
  D:\pt\9fb9bcd0b8026ca4af617bf97d81af30_ec9c5b.mp4_av_33.ts
  General #1
    ID : 1 (0x1)
    Complete name : D:\pt\9fb9bcd0b8026ca4af617bf97d81af30_ec9c5b.mp4_av_33.ts
    Format : MPEG-TS
    File size : 1.92 MiB
    Duration : 9s 0ms
    Overall bit rate mode : Variable
    Overall bit rate : 1 608 Kbps
  Video #256
    ID : 256 (0x100)
    Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
    Format : AVC
    Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
    Format profile : High@L4.1
    Format settings, CABAC : Yes
    Format settings, ReFrames : 3 frames
    Format settings, GOP : M=3, N=25
    Codec ID : 27
    Duration : 10s 0ms
    Bit rate mode : Variable
    Maximum bit rate : 10 000 Kbps
    Width : 1 280 pixels
    Height : 720 pixels
    Display aspect ratio : 16:9
    Frame rate : 25.000 fps
    Standard : PAL
    Color space : YUV
    Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
    Bit depth : 8 bits
    Scan type : Interlaced
    Scan order : Top Field First
    Color primaries : BT.709
    Transfer characteristics : BT.709
    Matrix coefficients : BT.709
  Audio #257
    ID : 257 (0x101)
    Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
    Format : AAC
    Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec
    Format version : Version 4
    Format profile : LC
    Muxing mode : ADTS
    Codec ID : 15
    Duration : 9s 984ms
    Bit rate mode : Variable
    Channel count : 2 channels
    Channel positions : Front: L R
    Sampling rate : 48.0 KHz
    Compression mode : Lossy
    Delay relative to video : -35ms
    Language : English
  Menu #4096
    ID : 4096 (0x1000)
    Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
    Duration : 9s 0ms
    List : 256 (0x100) (AVC) / 257 (0x101) (AAC, English)
    Language :  / English
    Service name : Service01
    Service provider : FFmpeg
    Service type : digital television
```

For comparison, here's the analysis of another version (this one works):

```
  D:\pt\ed737c7f4596d3091da353e81b8c1bf0.mp4_av_87.ts
  General #1
    ID : 1 (0x1)
    Complete name : D:\pt\ed737c7f4596d3091da353e81b8c1bf0.mp4_av_87.ts
    Format : MPEG-TS
    File size : 2.22 MiB
    Duration : 9s 984ms
    Overall bit rate mode : Variable
    Overall bit rate : 1 865 Kbps
  Video #256
    ID : 256 (0x100)
    Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
    Format : AVC
    Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
    Format profile : High@L3.0
    Format settings, CABAC : No
    Format settings, ReFrames : 1 frame
    Codec ID : 27
    Duration : 9s 980ms
    Width : 1 280 pixels
    Height : 720 pixels
    Display aspect ratio : 16:9
    Frame rate : 25.000 fps
    Color space : YUV
    Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
    Bit depth : 8 bits
    Scan type : Progressive
  Audio #257
    ID : 257 (0x101)
    Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
    Format : AAC
    Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec
    Format version : Version 4
    Format profile : LC
    Muxing mode : ADTS
    Codec ID : 15
    Duration : 9s 984ms
    Bit rate mode : Variable
    Channel count : 2 channels
    Channel positions : Front: L R
    Sampling rate : 44.1 KHz
    Compression mode : Lossy
    Delay relative to video : 12ms
  Menu #4096
    ID : 4096 (0x1000)
    Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
    List : 256 (0x100) (AVC) / 257 (0x101) (AAC)
    Service name : Service01
    Service provider : FFmpeg
    Service type : digital television
```

Here are are mediainfo comparison of two files.

[mediainfo comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54IID.jpg)

The only other thing I can think of is level `High @L4.1` where the video image is abnormal, while the normal/usual level is `High @L3.0`, but according to https://developer.apple.com Iphone 6 and later support **High @L4.1**.

[image]

My question is what can cause this to happen : H.264 with profile `High @L4.1` not displaying on iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 7?

Comment: Not a **programming** question. Maybe use same account to ask at : **https://apple.stackexchange.com/**? or ask at : **https://video.stackexchange.com/**? Finally what's wrong with using a different profile like `High @L3.1` the image quality cannot be so different, right?

Comment: @VC.One  yes,it seems like that it has nothing to do with the profile.

Comment: The main differences are... **Not Working** = `High@L4.1` + 
`CABAC : Yes` + `Scan type : Interlaced`... versus...  **Working** = `High@L3.0` + `CABAC : No` + `Scan type : Progressive`. Fix the H.264 encoder settings and make new `.ts` to test on iPhone.

Comment: @VC.One  It seems like that the iphone does not support "Scan type : Interlaced" video,which was also discussed in https://forums.imore.com/ask-question/392739-why-cant-iphone-playback-60fps-mp4-videos.html

Comment: The reason is explicit now.It is because the `Scan type`  of `Not Working` is Interlaced.When I convert it to a new ts using format factory,is works normally.